# how to insert newline in multiline textbox for horizontal scrollbar for compact framework 2.0 using c#

Tags: c#, compact-framework

i'm working on .net compact framework 2.0 using c#. i have to set horizontal scrollbar of multiline textbox.

i have done following step:
wordwrap = false and multiline = true

problem is that when i'm giving to a long text, they are overlap to each other means not going to new line.

i have tried enviorment.newline but it not supported by WinCE and also tried \r\n but it's also not working. 
please tell how to get a new line in this situation.
pls help I have to do it ASAP.

Comment: its very strange that"\r\n" is not supported... there must be somthing wrong with what you are doing..can you show us some code

Comment: please provide the asp:textbox tag so that we can check whats wrong with that...

Answer (score 0):

set ScrollBars to Both (just guessing)

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the textbox control you can generate multi-line data for the text value by selecting the arrow at the far right of the edit box in the designer.  This will drop down a control for entering multi-line text that does allow using the enter key.

Alternately, you can do it in code with "\r\n" or if you like living dangerous do that in the designer code.  It does not work in the designer directly since that input is escaped.